# WordPress Multisite: Showing wp post to Static Html site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, multisite

How can I show WP posts to HTML static page?

I already know for WP singal site this code works fine which is given in this tutorial:

https://www.cocoonfxmedia.co.uk/blog/displaying-wordpress-posts-in-html-page
this working fine for singular site
But this code is not working for wp multisites its giving "`Database connecting error`"

Comment: You need to connect with the Database of Wordpress site to show the Posts in it. That will not be a static website. It is dynamic in nature. It is not clear what you want to achieve. Could you explain?

Comment: You can get the posts of your wordpress website with the Rest API using javascript (for example vue js would be an easy to implement choice) to show the posts on an external html page. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Just need to show post of site from wp multisite in html page but dont know how to connect database via php code?

Comment: @rank Hy yes can you share that reset API tutorial or code?

Comment: I added my answer using vue js, hope it helps!

Comment: thanks @rank its doing same thing and working fine as for learning i just want to ask can we do same thing you did with php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the posts of your wordpress website with the rest api and use javascript to display the posts on a static html website.

I will give you a code example using Vue JS.

On your html page, you include vue js with adding this to your `<head>` section:

```
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

That's all you have to do to use vue js, great.

Now we need a javascript file, for example call it `app.js` and include this at the bottom of your html page using:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Inside of this `app.js` file you are getting the posts and saving it to `posts: []`. Put this code inside of the javascript file:

```
new Vue({
el: '#posts',
data: {
    posts: [],
},
mounted() {
    fetch("https://yourWordpressURLhere.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=20&_embed=wp:term,wp:featuredmedia")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data => {
            this.posts= data;
        }))
}
});
```

In this code, we create a new vue instance and assign it to the element with id `#posts`, we then get the data from the wordpress page inside of `fetch` and use `&_embed` to also get the featured image and the post terms (maybe you need this in your output).

For your reference, if you need to get other post types:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/

So we now have our posts in the `data` object. We can now use this data in our html page inside the div with the id `#posts`. You have to include the following code inside of the `<body>` of your html page:

```
<div id="posts">
    <div v-bind:key="post.title.rendered" v-for="post in posts">
        <a v-bind:href="post.link"><img v-bind:src="post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].media_details.sizes.medium_large.source_url"></a>
        <a v-bind:href="post.link"><h4 v-html="post.name"></h4></a>
        <p v-html="post.title.rendered"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `v-for` loops through your post and will always display the div container with a featured image (in medium size) and post titles, linked to the detail page of the post.

---

So with using wordpress as a backend and vue js as frontend javascript framework, you can show your wordpress posts on a static html page.

Of course there are other ways using Rest API and showing wordpress posts with javascript. But Vue JS is a state of the art framework and has a very good performance, so I would recommend using it.

Comment: thanks @rank its doing same thing and working fine as for learning i just want to ask can we do same thing you did with php code?

Comment: glad to help! this would be another question. if you like to, you can create the new question and post the link here in the comments so i get notified. please make sure you tried searching first, there could be similar questions already answered. thank you, have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you want to fetch data from a database and show them on a page there's no way it's considered a static page.

The only thing I can think about is to fetch the database with a script (i.e. PHP) that creates an HTML static page copying and pasting the data on the database itself.

I would fetch the database via PHP as Wordpress do https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

and use this code to create the document from the data of the database [How to create new html pages on a server via html/javascript form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683251/how-to-create-new-html-pages-on-a-server-via-html-javascript-form-input)

In this way you'll create a new static HTML page with the data taken from the database.